# is static checker the same as static analyzer?

Tags: static-analysis

in some literatures the term "static checker" is used. for example https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2872362.2872364. I know what is static analyzer (we use PDG, CFG, AST and ... for analyzing a program before it runs). but what do they mean by static checker? is "static checker" the same as "static analyzer"?

Comment: how can I write a static checker for a c program to find its bugs?

Comment: You don’t write a static checker to find bugs in a c program. You write a static checker if you work for a company that writes software development tools used by millions of developers.

Comment: is "static checker" the same as "static analyzer" or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer, perhaps, should only be a comment but...

**TL;DR; Yes, they are the same thing.**

Longer answer:

In software engineering, we love to overload terms - using the same term for several different (sometimes incompatible) meanings.

We also are often non-standard in our terminology... using multiple terms for (broadly) the same thing; eg the following are all (broadly) synonym pairs:

- Static Analysis v Static/Source Code Analysis (although the former is, perhaps, broader in scope than just source-code, and can analyse data or models etc)
- Static Analyser v Static Checker (although, it could be argued that the former does Static Analysis, the later just Static Code Analysis)

In most instances, I would suggest that the each pair of terms can be used interchangeably, although I would (personally) recommend the left hand term is the "best" to use; the right hand term is a sub-set of the full.

Typically when someone talks about Static (Code) Analysis, they mean the process of running a Static Analyser/Checker on a set of source files, to check for conformance with coding rules (eg MISRA) - this may also measure some metrics.

So, yes, I suggest that (at least in most cases) a *Static Analyser* is the same thing as a *Static Checker*.

--
Disclaimer: for the avoidance of doubt, this post offers my personal opinion, and this view does not necessary reflect that of my employer, LDRA Ltd, who produce such *Static Analysis* tools.